# sum squared möbius function

Tags: number-theory

I would like to prove the following equality

$$\sum_{n=1}^N \mu^2(n) = \sum_{k=1}^{\sqrt{N}} \mu(k) \cdot \lfloor N / k^2 \rfloor$$

with N a square number.

Can anyone give me a hint?

p.s. I know already that

$$\frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(2s) } = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{ \mu^2(n)}{n^{s}}$$

Perhaps this can help?

Comment: Notice that $\mu^2(n)$ is always $0$ or $1$ depending on wether $n$ is squarefree or not. So you can easily interpret the left-hand side...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Big hint: The left side counts something, and the right side counts the same thing via an inclusion-exclusion argument.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint:**  Since $$\sum_{d|n} \mu(d)=\left\{ \begin{array}{cc}
1 & \text{if }n=1\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{array}\right\} $$ we have that

$$\sum_{d\leq N}\mu(d)^{2}=\sum_{d\leq N}\sum_{k^{2}|d}\mu(k).$$  Now, try switching the order of summation.